# Heat transfer coefficients

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity

I am trying to make a model of non-stationary heating on a plate and I have questions considering coefficients. I am using explicit method to solve it (have to use it). I am not sure if I am using the right coefficients. I decided the plate will be made of steel(0,5% C) and found that thermal diffusivity coefficients (k/(rho*cp)) are  a_steel = 14.74*10^(-6), thermal diffusivity of air a_air = 1.9*10^(-5). 
I have to implement also a heat source and I don't know what coefficient I should use for that.

As it's a 2D problem, my solving code looks like this:

```
dmx = (M0[iY,iX+1] + M0[iY,iX-1] - 2.0 * M0[iY,iX])/dx**2.0 # conduction in x-direction
        dmy = (M0[iY+1,iX] + M0[iY-1,iX] - 2.0 * M0[iY,iX])/dy**2.0 # conduction in y-direction
M_new[iY,iX] = M0[iY, iX] + k_diffusion*dt*(dmx+dmy) + dt*k_heating*heat_source(X[iX],     Y[iY], M0)  - dt*k_cooling*(M0[iY,iX]-T_ok)
```

My questions are: am I using the right coefficients? If yes, what coefficient should I use for the source?
One more: what's the difference between non-stationary and stationary source?

Thank you!